# CSS Fit BG Image?

Tags: html, css, position, background-image, image-resizing

For days now....I have being trying to fix/centre my background image in the correct way.
I have attached a example to being show this.

[image]

Figure A: I need my bg image to full the full screen (custom size which fit ok).
Figure B: I also need my bg image to fit to the vertical res, and the the horizon to be centred as I asjust my brower window etc.

I had google to hell and back... with no good solutions? is it possible to do this? or am I asking to much for css/html5

ok here is my code: and image below if u want to take a look...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkYJs.jpg)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
 margin: 0px;
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #999;
 text-align: center;
 background-image: url(bg.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100%;
 background-color: #975d7f;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you include your HTML and CSS for this, please?

Comment: Did you try something like this in your css: my-image { width: 100% !important; height: auto !impotant; }. my-image would be the class name you assign to you image tag. Actually, it‘s better if you post the HTML and CSS code you have been trying till now.

Comment: without your code included it will hard for people to help you. Please add your code

Comment: I added the code but the bg image is gone! you can add one of your own for example

Comment: ok the image is attached now see link https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkYJs.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what you're looking for, but I think this might fit your needs.  If you want the image to cover the full height of the screen you need to set the height of the html and body tags to 100%.

```
html {height:100%;}
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #999;
    text-align: center;
    background: #975d7f url("bg.jpg") no-repeat top center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Also, I used the "shorthand" version of the background css property.